# Independent increments implies Markov property?

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-process, measurable-functions

I am trying to prove the following:
If $X =\{X_t : t\geq 0\}$ is a real-valued stochastic process with independent increments then it is also a Markov process:
$$
    p\{X_t \in A | \mathcal{F}_s\} = p\{X_t \in A | X_s\}, \quad \forall A \in \mathcal{F}.
    $$
where $\mathcal{F} = \sigma(X) = \{\mathcal{F}_s:s \geq 0\}$ denotes the natural filtration and $\mathcal{F}_s = \sigma(X_k: 0\leq k \leq s$).

This should be enough to prove but I can't really justify what I've done:
Supose $f$ is bounded and measurable. For every $t\geq s \geq 0$,$X_s $ is $\mathcal{F}_s$-measurable and the increment $X_t - X_s$ is independent of $\mathcal{F}_s$, therefore
\begin{align*}
    \mathbb{E}[f(X_t) | \mathcal{F}_s] &= E[f(X_t - X_s + X_s) | \mathcal{F}_s]\\
    &= E[f(X_t - X_s + y)]\bigg\rvert_{y = X_s} \\
    &= \mathbb{E}[f(X_t - X_s + y) | \sigma(X_s)] \bigg\rvert_{y = X_s}\\
    &= \mathbb{E}[f(X_t) | \sigma(X_s)].
\end{align*}

Now is enough to consider $f = \mathbb{1}_A$ and this concludes. Is the third equality right? Am I missing some steps in between? Something tells me that the tower property should be applied in there but I just don't see it :/

I want to write a clear proof about this and want to justify every detail.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you assuming $X_0=0$?

Comment: Yes, the initial law is null in this case.